# Bind an action to a combination of 3 or more keys using Key Bindings

Tags: java, swing, key-bindings, modifiers

I understand how to use Modifiers with Key Bindings like `CTRL_DOWN_MASK + some key` but I want to be able to bind a specific action to when Control, some letter (i.e. 'W'), and the up arrow are all being pressed. Something like `CTRL_DOWN_MASK + some key + Up Arrow`.

I'd be using this to change the volume of a certain sounds clip.  So when I have `CTRL_DOWN_MASK + W + Up Arrow` all pressed the volume will increase for the sound clip assigned to the W JButton and if I have `CTRL_DOWN_MASK + W + Down Arrow` the volume will decrease for said sound clip.

```
    public void bindKey(JPanel base)
    {

        base.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(key, InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK),"Volume"+key);
        base.getActionMap().put("Volume"+key, new AbstractAction(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                //if(Up Arrow is being pressed.)
                setGain(currentGain() + 1.0f);

                //if(Down Arrow is being pressed.)
                setGain(currentGain() - 1.0f);
            }
        });
     }
```

Comment: you have [to do logic yourself](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13440608/203657)

Comment: @kleopatra With your answer in that post, how would you implement that into an existing action map.  I don't understand what you are doing with extending the AbstractAction you create and how you assign an action to the mapping of keys A + S + D.

Answer (score 3):

You'd need more hands... I think that's why they limit it to modifiers and a main key.  Have you considered ctrl+w starts the interface where you can then press up or down to adjust volume?

Your other option is to map key bindings on both the ctrl+w and ctrl+up keys.  Then whenever they're both active, do your action.  You'd need to set flags and have two mappings - one for pressed and one for released.  You can see the [Keystroke class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/KeyStroke.html#getKeyStroke%28java.lang.String%29) for more details on setting up the keys for mapping.

Comment: Well I do have 2 hands, so it is feasible to press Crtl + W and then up or down arrows with my other hand.  But thank you for your suggestion, I will try adding both those mappings and see what I can do.

Comment: When you say set flags, what do you mean by that?

Comment: @Alex Yes - you're absolutely right that it's feasible.  It's usually just not as convenient (which is generally the goal of bindings) - that's probably why it's not built it.

When I say flags, I mean boolean variables which tell you if and event has happened.  So you have two events for ctrl+w (one for pressing and one for releasing) would set a boolean variable indicating it's pressed.  Up and down will have their own event that first checks the flag - if the flag is set (true), it continues to adjust volume.  Otherwise it does nothing.